# Onsen UI タブからタブへの移動はできるのでしょうか？

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

表題の通りです。出来るのかできないのかもわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

```
<ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Home</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="fav.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Favorites</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="settings.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Settings</span>
  </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>

<ons-template id="home.html">
  ここから
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="fav.html">
  ...
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="settings.html">
  ここへ移動したい
</ons-template>
```

Comment: 余談ですが、Onsen UI `ons-tabbar`の使い方の例には間違いがあり、`active="true"`は初期に有効にしたいタブに対して設定します。現状だと`Settings`が有効になるはずです。

Answer (score 1):

`<ons-tabbar>`にはタブを切り替えるためのメソッド`setActiveTab()`が用意されているので、それを利用すると良いでしょう。
下記のスニペットを実行してみてください。

```js
angular.module('app', ['onsen'])
.controller('PageController', function($scope){
  $scope.changeTab = function(index){
    $scope.tabbar.setActiveTab(index);
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.13/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.13/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.13/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.13/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <ons-tabbar var="tabbar">
    <ons-tab icon="home" page="page1.html" active="true"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab icon="user" page="page2.html"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab icon="gear" page="page3.html"></ons-tab>
  </ons-tabbar>
  <ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="PageController">
      <h1>page1</h1>
      <ons-button ng-click="changeTab(0)">Tab1</ons-button>
      <ons-button ng-click="changeTab(1)">Tab2</ons-button>
      <ons-button ng-click="changeTab(2)">Tab3</ons-button>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="PageController">
      <h1>page2</h1>
      <ons-button ng-click="changeTab(0)">Tab1</ons-button>
      <ons-button ng-click="changeTab(1)">Tab2</ons-button>
      <ons-button ng-click="changeTab(2)">Tab3</ons-button>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="page3.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="PageController">
      <h1>page3</h1>
      <ons-button ng-click="changeTab(0)">Tab1</ons-button>
      <ons-button ng-click="changeTab(1)">Tab2</ons-button>
      <ons-button ng-click="changeTab(2)">Tab3</ons-button>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
</body>
```

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。
おかげさまで思うような処理が実行できました。

Comment: @ナッツ 問題が解決したということでしたら、この質問が解決済みであることを示すために回答の承認をご検討ください。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

たぶん古いOnsenUIでも使えると思います。
質問を見る限りタブの番号は0～2ですので、
`$(".tab-bar__item:eq(2)").click();`
上記のように`eq(タブ番号)`で移動できるかと思います。

おまけですが、現在選択されているタブは下記で調べられます。
`ons-page`のコントローラで初期化しとけば移動したときのタブ番号が分かります。

```js
//ページのコントローラ
module.controller('controller', function($scope) {
 ons.ready(function() {
     $scope.tab_changed = function($index, $tabitem){
      tab_scope.ActiveTabIndex=$index;
     };
 });
});
```

```html
<ons-tabbar var="tab_scope" on-active-tab-changed="tab_changed($index, $tabItem)">
 <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">
  <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
  <span style="font-size: 14px">Home</span>
 </ons-tab>
 <ons-tab page="fav.html" active="true">
  <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon>
  <span style="font-size: 14px">Favorites</span>
 </ons-tab>
 <ons-tab page="settings.html" active="true">
  <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-icon>
  <span style="font-size: 14px">Settings</span>
 </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

逆に言うと初期化しないと使えないので
初期化できない場合などはタブのクラスを見て
選択状態のクラスを探してやることで無理やり出せます

```
/**
 * タブ番号を返却する
 **/
function get_active_tab(){
    var tabno=-1;
    var elements = $(".tab-bar__item");
    for(key in elements){
        if(0 <= elements[key].className.indexOf("active")){tabno=key;break;}
    }
    return tabno;
}
```

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。  
$('.tab-bar__item:eq(2)').click();  
上記を試してみましたが、反応しませんでした。  
他に対策はありますでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: この方法だとjQueryが読み込まれていないと動かないと思います。